# Invoking bpel webservice from Java

Tags: java, bpel

I need to Invoke a Bpel Webservices from Java.

what is the way to invoke, should i use restful Webservice or soap base Webservice?

Comment: This post maybe useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708617/are-there-any-bpel-tools-that-use-restful-web-services-instead-of-big-web-servic

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/) which has both a SOAP and a REST interface depending on which you need.